# Laravel: Select specific unique columns from database

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get only a specific number of columns from a database. (condominium details)

But there are condominiums with the same name, so If two of them have the same name, I want to output them in view only once. Right now I have this code, that actually lists the unique condominiums but seems to not be getting the remaining columns data. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

`Controller.php`

```
public function condominiums(){
    $page_name= "Condominiums List";

    $condos = Asset::get('condominium_name','condominium_contact_person','condominium_address', 'condominium_email', 'condominium_phone')->unique('condominium_name');

    return view('condominiums')->with('page_name', $page_name)->with('condos', $condos);
}
```

`View.blade.php`

```
@foreach ($condos as $condominium)
        <p>{{$condominium->condominium_name}}</p>
        <p>{{$condominium->condominium_contact_person}}</p>
        <p>{{$condominium->condominium_address}}</p>
        <p>{{$condominium->condominium_email}}</p>
        <p>{{$condominium->condominium_phone}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query builder's get method should receive an array with the field names.

```
$condos = Asset::get(['condominium_name','condominium_contact_person','condominium_address', 'condominium_email', 'condominium_phone'])->unique('condominium_name');
```

should work for you.